# Help Needed. Cam/PC link

Tags: camera, youtube

Hello fellow enthusiasts,
I am in need of help and would be very thankful to anyone who can take a few minutes and help me solve this issue.

Here is my problem.
I would like to open a Youtube channel and I want to have a facecam in an upper corner(you know, like gaming channels usually do while gaming) but have no camera. What I do have is my Sony Xperia Z1 Compact. Please tell me(with a decent explanation) if there is a possible way to record videos with my phone but **save it directly on the PC hard drive** so I can later use it when editing. Saving it on my phone and then moving it on the PC later is not an option. Already tried IP CAM and other similar apps but I am not satisfied with the results.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Spent the last hour looking for an answer to your question,  think I got a solution for you. The app "PlayTo Universal" $4.99/US and "Cast2TV-PRO" $2.99/US, both available from play store will stream directly to the PC from your android. They should work for your "game face cam".

Good luck!!